# Font-size for GWT TextBox and Button can't be set

Tags: css, gwt, button, textbox, font-size

I have a `GWT` `button` and I want to change the `font-size` of it to `15pt`.
In my `Project.css`, I have set it's `font-size`.

```
.gwt-Button {
    font-size: 15pt;
}
```

But this `CSS` style doesn't change the `font-size` of my Button. Is there any other way I could change the `font-size` of my `button`?

Comment: my `TextBox` has the same issue with my `Button`.

Comment: Is there any other way I could change the font-size of my button? That is the way it is usually done. Looks like your css is not being applied. Try using a different unit such as em or % and see if it alters the font-size. If not, you might have problems of your Project.css file not being linked probally to your html file. Are other styles being applied?

Comment: hi. my `css` styles are being applied to my project. actually, I set a `width` for my `button` and it applies but not in `font-size`. I just don't know why?

Comment: hey, i've already tried using other units but still no effect. i've tried `EM`, `%`, `px`. :(

Comment: give it a color: red; or font-weight: bold; and see if it effects the button text?

Comment: yes, it create an effect to the `button` `text`.

Comment: see if you have the !important decralation set on the font-size some where in your code. That way your set styles may not have any effect. Try to set the font-size as an in-line style and see if that helps.

Comment: Don't leave the !important there. It should only be used as a troubleshooting tool, as in you case. You will have management nightmares later. As suspected somwhere the font-size is not being applied beacuse of the specificity/weight of the selector. An alternative would be is to increase the specificity/weight by using an ID selector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using a GWT theme, it might very well define the fond-size, so you have to make sure your stylesheet is either loaded after (so it redefines the font-size) or use a more specific selector (`input.gwt-Button` for instance).
It really depends how, when and where you load your stylesheet and/or the theme stylesheet.

Note that you can inherit the <*theme-name*>Resources module (e.g. CleanResources instead of Clean) to have the theme's resources copied to the output folder but not automatically loaded, and then load the stylesheet from your HTML host page (using a `<link rel=stylesheet href=…>` just like any stylesheet), so it's easier to put your custom styles after.

Answer (score 0):

you should not use default stylenames like .gwt-Button because they can have precedence problems . You can set new stylename with .setStyleName("customButton")  and then use it in CSS file.

example:

```
.customButton{
font-size: 15pt;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You only have to add the !important flag to your style sheet like

```
.gwt-Button {
    font-size: 15pt !important;
}
```

Or use your own style name for your button, e.g. `myButton.addStyleName("myButtonStyle");` in your code and

```
.myButtonStyle {
    font-size: 15pt !important;
 }
```

in your Project.css file.

This works the same way for your TextBox.