# GWT button background not working

Tags: css, gwt, uibinder

I am new to GWT/uiBinder (latest version of GWT and testing under latest Eclipse) and really puzzled. My CSS for buttons is ...

```
/* --button-- */
.gwt-Button {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #0F0;
    background: #F00;    /* this gets ignored */
}
```

The background does nothing, the rest works.

I have tested that this CSS entry does something by changing the color and seeing that it works. I have also tried "background-color" (I have seen both in various docs). The background never changes.

I also tested a gwt-TextBox as follows and it works just fine.

```
/* --text box-- */
.gwt-TextBox {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #0F0;
    background: Beige;
}
```

Note: I know that sometimes while testing you have to refresh the web page to see your changes.

Note: I can set the button background by using a CSS entry called "myButton" and using styleName='myButton' it in the uiBinder entry.

Note: The button is in a Layer in a LayoutPanel in a north:DockLayoutPanel in an east:DockLayoutPanel.

Help!

Comment: Are you sure that the element has the class "gwt-Button"?

Comment: Since the other fields alter the button (like size and color), the button is connected to that CSS entry.

Comment: What browser are you using?  Can you inspect the element and see what CSS rule is overriding your CSS entry?

Comment: IE9, can you tell me how to inspect, if I "view source" I just see the simple HTML that launches everything, not anything that is actually painting the page that I see.

Comment: For IE9 [instructions are here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565627(v=vs.85).aspx#styletool).  In chrome you can just right click the element and choose "Inspect Element".  I bet that you have two "background" rules for the "gwt-Button" style and since the default GWT on is coming first that is the one that is applied.  The developer tools of either browser should go a long way to tell you what is going on.

Comment: OK, I see that standard.css is below MyStuff.css, in fact IE9 lets you de-select standard.css and then the button does what I want. So how do I get my CSS to override standard.css (get applied after standard.css)? I am referencing my CSS in the main HTML file now.
By the way, as a beginner with GWT (and Web dev in general), I really appreciate the patient help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7833358/635411

You can use a more specific selector like the other answer suggests:

```
/* --button-- */
button.gwt-Button {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #0F0;
    background: #F00;
}
```

Personally, I try to avoid overwriting the default styles because of the precedence issues.

Comment: Yes, this of course works, but with dozens of buttons (and other control elements too) to have a style override, the uibinder gets bigger and harder to read. Thanks, this may be the way to go.

Comment: @TomZ Your buttons are in another container right?  Write a specific CSS rule for that: `.myContainer .gwt-Button {...}`.  This should override the default.

Answer (score 2):

I think this should solve your problem

```
.gwt-Button {
         font-size: 16px;
         font-weight: normal;
         color: #0F0;
         background: #F00 !important; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include this line before you make any changes to the background of `gwt-Button`

```
background-image:initial !important;
```

The problem you're having is that you're trying to set a background color, when `gwt-Button` uses a background image, so the image goes over your background color, making it seem like your css is being ignored.

Answer (score 0):

there is a simpler way 
you need to remove the gwt-Button style and then add whatever color you like 
`

```
Button button=new Button();
button.removeStyleName("gwt-Button");
button.getElement().getStyle().setbackgroundColor("#F00");
//incase you need to remove the default border style aswell
button.getElement().getStyle().setBorderStyle(BorderStyle.NONE);
```

`